# How do I re-link the library use require? (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, export, node-modules, require

For example
I have ***file 1***

```
[{"a1":1}]
```

And ***file 2***

```
var obj1 = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./файл 1.JSON" , "UTF-8"));
module.exports.obj1 = obj1
```

I start ***program***...

```
for(i=0; ; i++) {
  console.log(require('./файл 2').a1);
  let bb = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./файл 1.JSON" , "UTF-8"));
  console.log(bb.a1);
  (there pause for slowed)
}
```

And at that time I correct ***file 1***. Then I will see it in ***fs***, but don't see in ***require***.
Now the question: how to make, so that ***require*** show the new value?

Comment: You need something like `require-from-string` package to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

When node executes your program and executes a `require` statement, it loads any modules. It then caches those modules so that subsequent requests for the same module give the same code. So in your example, on the first time through the loop, file 2 is going to be initialized with whatever value it reads from the JSON file and it won't be re-initialized.

Modules are intended to be static bundles of code and using `require` to include the same module multiple times is supposed to return the same module. For dynamic values like your JSON file, use `fs` functions to access the values at the time they're needed.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me. In file 2 i write: function f() {
  return ( JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./file 1.JSON" , "UTF-8")) )
}
module.exports.f = f
And this is work